# Find multicast ip address form my GPL application distributed free

Tags: multicast

Which could be a good IP multicast for a free GPL application, free and usable, NOT to route traffic on the internet but that it remains within the private network of home?

Something in range 239.0.0.0/8 is usable? Not route traffic over internet?

Originally i think 224.23.45.78 but [apparently it's reserved](http://myip.ms/view/ip_addresses/3759615232/224.23.45.0_224.23.45.255)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe just look here?

http://www.iana.org/assignments/multicast-addresses/multicast-addresses.xhtml

Usually you would just use 224.0.0.1